# Accessing function in constructor with typescript

Tags: typescript

I am not too sure how to access a function declared in an interface inside of my constructor. I have a simple inferface

```
export interface ILog  {
    extendLog($delegate: any): ng.ILogService;
}
```

and for my constructor

```
export class LogConfig implements ILog{

    static $inject = ["$provide","$delegate"];
    constructor(public $provide : ng.auto.IProvideService,
                public $delegate: ng.ILogService
    ){
        $provide.decorator('$log',extendLog ); 
    }

    extendLog($delegate: any): ng.ILogService {

        var debugFunction = $delegate.debug;
        $delegate.debug = (...args: any[]): void => {
            var now = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
            args[0] = now + ' - ' + args[0];
            debugFunction.apply(null, args);
        };
        return $delegate;
    }
}
```

`extendLog` is giving and error though

```
Cannot find name 'extendLog'
```

Am i even going about this the right way? Just trying to create a simple decorator.

Comment: maybe `this.extendLog`?

Comment: oh wow .. that is a n00b overlook right there. You can add the answer , ill accept

Comment: hehe, not necessary, minor typo/mistakes like that don't need answers imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this.

```
$provide.decorator('$log',this.extendLog);
```